# Loading values to nested dicts from a list

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested, mapping

I have a CSV files which has a header like this:

```
cpus/0/compatible   clocks/HSE/compatible   ../frequency    memories/flash/compatible   ../address  ../size [and so on...]
```

I'm able to parse that header into a nested dictionaries which may look like this:

```
{'clocks': {'HSE': {'compatible': '[1]',
                    'frequency': '[2]'}},
 'cpus': {'0': {'compatible': '[0]'}},
 'memories': {'bkpsram': {'address': '[13]',
                          'compatible': '[12]',
                          'size': '[14]'},
              'ccm': {'address': '[7]',
                      'compatible': '[6]',
                      'size': '[8]'},
              'flash': {'address': '[4]',
                        'compatible': '[3]',
                        'size': '[5]'},
              'sram': {'address': '[10]',
                       'compatible': '[9]',
                       'size': '[11]'}},
 'pin-controller': {'GPIOA': {'enabled': '[16]'},
                    'GPIOB': {'enabled': '[17]'},
                    'GPIOC': {'enabled': '[18]'},
                    'GPIOD': {'enabled': '[19]'},
                    'GPIOE': {'enabled': '[20]'},
                    'GPIOF': {'enabled': '[21]'},
                    'GPIOG': {'enabled': '[22]'},
                    'GPIOH': {'enabled': '[23]'},
                    'GPIOI': {'enabled': '[24]'},
                    'GPIOJ': {'enabled': '[25]'},
                    'GPIOK': {'enabled': '[26]'},
                    'compatible': '[15]'}}
```

(it is a `dict` object, printed with `pprint()`)

The values of keys which look like `'[<number>]'` reflect the index of column in the CSV file from which the data should be loaded.

As I mainly use C/C++ I would actually love to have pointers/references in Python, as then I would just put a pointer to a list element in each value and for each row I could modify list contents, but I think there's no way to obtain such behaviour easily in Python.

So now I plan to dump this dictionary into a string and perform following 3 modifications in a row:

- replace `{` with `{{`,
- replace `}` with `}}`,
- replace `'[<number>]'` with `{<number>}`.

After that I will be able to "load" the data with something like this `ast.literal_eval(dictAsStr.format(*rowFromCsv))`, but it seems like a waste of time to convert the whole dict to a string and then back to a dict...

Am I missing some other obvious solution here? The format of the CSV and the way I load the header is not fixed, I may alter that easily, but **I would really like a solution which would not boil down to "visit each key recursively and load appropriate value from current row manually"**.

From the CSV file I load each row as a list of strings, for example:

```
['["ARM,Cortex-M4", "ARM,ARMv7-M"]',
 '["ST,STM32-HSE", "fixed-clock"]',
 '0',
 '["on-chip-flash"]',
 '0x8000000',
 '131072',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '["on-chip-ram"]',
 '0x20000000',
 '65536',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '["ST,STM32-GPIOv2-pin-controller"]',
 'False',
 'False',
 'False',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'False',
 '',
 '',
 '']
```

Now I would like to insert the values from each loaded row (list of strings) into appropriate keys in the nested dictionary, so following with the examples above I would like to get:

```
{'clocks': {'HSE': {'compatible': '["ST,STM32-HSE", "fixed-clock"]',
                    'frequency': '0'}},
 'cpus': {'0': {'compatible': '["ARM,Cortex-M4", "ARM,ARMv7-M"]'}},
 'memories': {'bkpsram': {'address': '',
                          'compatible': '',
                          'size': ''},
              'ccm': {'address': '',
                      'compatible': '',
                      'size': ''},
              'flash': {'address': '0x8000000',
                        'compatible': '["on-chip-flash"]',
                        'size': '131072'},
              'sram': {'address': '0x20000000',
                       'compatible': '["on-chip-ram"]',
                       'size': '65536'}},
 'pin-controller': {'GPIOA': {'enabled': 'False'},
                    'GPIOB': {'enabled': 'False'},
                    'GPIOC': {'enabled': 'False'},
                    'GPIOD': {'enabled': ''},
                    'GPIOE': {'enabled': ''},
                    'GPIOF': {'enabled': ''},
                    'GPIOG': {'enabled': ''},
                    'GPIOH': {'enabled': 'False'},
                    'GPIOI': {'enabled': ''},
                    'GPIOJ': {'enabled': ''},
                    'GPIOK': {'enabled': ''},
                    'compatible': '["ST,STM32-GPIOv2-pin-controller"]'}}
```

For completeness, here are a few first lines from the CSV file I would like to load. The first column is not part of the dictionary presented above, as it is used for indexing.

```
chip,cpus/0/compatible,clocks/HSE/compatible,../frequency,memories/flash/compatible,../address,../size,memories/ccm/compatible,../address,../size,memories/sram/compatible,../address,../size,memories/bkpsram/compatible,../address,../size,pin-controller/compatible,pin-controller/GPIOA/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOB/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOC/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOD/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOE/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOF/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOG/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOH/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOI/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOJ/enabled,pin-controller/GPIOK/enabled
STM32F401CB,"[""ARM,Cortex-M4"", ""ARM,ARMv7-M""]","[""ST,STM32-HSE"", ""fixed-clock""]",0,"[""on-chip-flash""]",0x8000000,131072,,,,"[""on-chip-ram""]",0x20000000,65536,,,,"[""ST,STM32-GPIOv2-pin-controller""]",False,False,False,,,,,False,,,
STM32F401CC,"[""ARM,Cortex-M4"", ""ARM,ARMv7-M""]","[""ST,STM32-HSE"", ""fixed-clock""]",0,"[""on-chip-flash""]",0x8000000,262144,,,,"[""on-chip-ram""]",0x20000000,65536,,,,"[""ST,STM32-GPIOv2-pin-controller""]",False,False,False,,,,,False,,,
STM32F401CD,"[""ARM,Cortex-M4"", ""ARM,ARMv7-M""]","[""ST,STM32-HSE"", ""fixed-clock""]",0,"[""on-chip-flash""]",0x8000000,393216,,,,"[""on-chip-ram""]",0x20000000,98304,,,,"[""ST,STM32-GPIOv2-pin-controller""]",False,False,False,,,,,False,,,
```

The code used to parse the header:

```
import csv

with open("some-path-to-CSV-file") as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    header = next(csvReader)
    previousKeyElements = header[1].split('/')
    dictionary = {}
    for index, key in enumerate(header[1:]):
        keyElements = key.split('/')
        i = 0
        while keyElements[i] == '..':
            i += 1
        keyElements[0:i] = previousKeyElements[0:-i]
        previousKeyElements = keyElements
        node = dictionary
        for keyElement in keyElements[:-1]:
            node = node.setdefault(keyElement, {})
        node[keyElements[-1]] = '[{}]'.format(index)
```

Comment: Can you show your sample output?

Comment: @Rakesh - what sample output you have in mind? There's no final output available, as I'm still wondering how to load that nicely, but - for simplicity - the values in CSV can be considered to be only strings. So I'm looking for a way of replacing the "tags" in the dictionary values with actual strings loaded from following rows in the CSV file. I will paste a few lines of the CSV file in a moment, but this is really "dense" when viewed as a text...

Comment: "As I mainly use C/C++ I would actually love to have pointers/references in Python, as then I would just put a pointer to a list element in each value and for each row I could modify list contents, but I think there's no way to obtain such behaviour easily in Python." => I don't clearly understand what you're trying to do here but if you explained the _real_ problem you're trying to solve instead of what you think is the solution we might suggest a working pythonic solution.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - yes, I am looking for a pythonic solution. I just described what solutions crossed my mind, nothing more. The problem is "clean way to load values from a list of strings (this is what I get from a CSV row) into a nested dictionaries (this is what I want in the end), possibly without a recursively visit of each key and load the value manually (as this is an obvious solution (; )".

Comment: @FreddieChopin yes I understand this - what I don't understand is what you're actually trying to do (what problem you're trying to solve). Could you at least add an example of the expected final output for the csv extract you posted ?

Comment: Oh and yes: the code used to parse the headers might be useful too.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - done, however I don't think the actual code to parse the header is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just using the actual row index (as integer) as value in the "parsed" header, ie:

```
{'clocks': {'HSE': {'compatible': 1,
                'frequency': 2}},
# etc
```

Then using recursion on a parsed header copy to populate it from the row values ?:

```
import csv
import sys
import copy
import pprint

def parse_header(header):
    previousKeyElements = header[1].split('/')
    dictionary = {}
    for index, key in enumerate(header[1:]):
        keyElements = key.split('/')
        i = 0
        while keyElements[i] == '..':
            i += 1
        keyElements[0:i] = previousKeyElements[0:-i]
        previousKeyElements = keyElements
        node = dictionary
        for keyElement in keyElements[:-1]:
            node = node.setdefault(keyElement, {})
        node[keyElements[-1]] = index
    return dictionary

def _rparse(d, k, v, row):
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for subk, subv in v.items():
            _rparse(v, subk, subv, row)
    elif isinstance(v, int):
        d[k] = row[v]
    else:
        raise ValueError("'v' should be either a dict or an int (got : %s(%s))" % (type(v), v))


def parse_row(header, row):
    struct = copy.deepcopy(header)
    for k, v in struct.items():
        _rparse(struct, k, v, row)
    return struct

def main(*args):
    path = args[0]
    with open(path) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = parse_header(next(reader))
        results = [parse_row(header, row[1:]) for row in reader]

    pprint.pprint(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Another solution (that might actually be faster) would be to build a reverse mapping with row indices as keys and dict "path" as values ie:

```
{0: ("cpus", "0", "compatible"),
 1: ("clocks", "HSE", "compatible"),
 2: ("clocks", "HSE", "frequency"),
 # etc
}
```

and then:

```
def parse_row(template, map, row):
   # 'template' is your parsed header dict
   struct = copy.deepcopy(template)
   target = struct  
   for index, path in map.items():
       for key in path[:-1]:
           target = target[key]
       target[key[-1] = row[index]
```

Oh and yes, as an added bonus, you may want to use `ast.literal_eval()` to turn your values into proper python types:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("False")
False
>>> ast.literal_eval('["on-chip-flash"]')
['on-chip-flash']
>>> ast.literal_eval('0x8000000')
134217728
>>> ast.literal_eval('["ARM,Cortex-M4", "ARM,ARMv7-M"]')
['ARM,Cortex-M4', 'ARM,ARMv7-M']
>>> ast.literal_eval("this should fail")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    this should fail
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


>>> def to_python(value):
...     try:
...         return ast.literal_eval(value)
...     except Exception as e:
...         return value
... 
>>> to_python('["on-chip-flash"]')
['on-chip-flash']
>>> to_python('wtf')
'wtf'
>>>
```

Comment: The first solution clearly falls into the "visit each key recursively and load appropriate value from current row manually" category, the second one is interesting, as it is "reversed".

Comment: Err, sorry yes I actually missed the part in your post about you wanting to avoid the "visit each key recursively" solution.